# get year from Date Excel cell value not working

Tags: excel, vba, datepart

I have the following code:

```
For rowIndex = rowOffset To 15
        Dim currentDate As Date
        Dim nextRowDate As Date
        currentDate = Cells(rowOffset, colIndex).Value
        nextRowDate = Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex).Value

        Dim currentYear As Date
        currentYear = DatePart("yyyy", currentDate)

        Dim nextYear As Date
        nextYear = DatePart("yyyy", nextRowDate)

        If currentYear <> nextYear Then
            Call RenderYearStyle(rowIndex, colIndex)
        Else
            Call ClearStyle(rowIndex, colIndex)
        End If
    Next rowIndex
```

Date Part or "Year" functions are not returning the year part of the date. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one correction to your own answer - `Year()` returns Integer, not String. Bring up Immediate window (Ctrl-G) type `?typename(year(now))` and press enter. VBE is smart that it convert the Integer to String for you in background.

```
?typename(year(now))
Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

the Year() function returns a String not a Date.. DOIIIII.

```
    Dim currentYear As String
    currentYear = year(currentDate)

    Dim nextYear As String
    nextYear = year(nextRowDate)
```

Comment: I can't yet ;) ( 2 days)